# Trouble filling Multiple Textbox values from other Textboxes when Checkbox is Clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I DID search but couldn't find anything that helped me to figure out my particular issue.  I've got textboxes for a customer address, and textboxes for a business address, and a checkbox to mark if the address should be the same.  I need to get the Checkbox to fill the business address with the customer address onclick and unfill them on onclick.  I've tried using a few different ways with jquery and straight javascript DOM manipulation, the most success I've had is in the following code, it only fills the biz_street textbox with the cust_street value though, and I don't understand why.  Some help would be greatly appreciated, either in jquery or straight javascript, can't use php (sadly).

Here it is on jsfiddle (as suggested by rjmunro, good idea :) ): http://jsfiddle.net/yN73w/1/ not working at all

Here is the jquery:

```
$("#same_box").click(function () {
var v = $("#cust_street").val();
var x = $("#cust_city").val();
var y = $("#cust_state").val();
var z = $("#cust_zip").val();

$("#biz_street").val(v);
$("#biz_city").val(x);
$("#biz_state").val(y);
$("#biz_zip").val(z);
});
```

Or more simply:

```
$("#same_box").click(function () {
$("#biz_street").val($("#cust_street").val());
$("#biz_city").val($("#cust_city").val());
$("#biz_state").val($("#cust_state").val());
$("#biz_zip").val($("#cust_zip").val());
});
```

And the HTML:

```
    <label id="cus_street_label">Street</label></br>
    <input type="text" name="cust_street" id="cust_street" style="width:90%" /></br>

<div id="cus_city">
    <label id="cus_city_label">City</label></br>
    <input type="text" name="cust_city" id="cust_city" style="width:100%" /></br>
</div>
<div id="cus_state">
    <label id="cus_state_label">State</label></br>
    <input type="text" name="cust_state" id="cust_state" style="width:70%" /></br>
</div>
<div id="cus_zip">
    <label id="cus_zip_label">Zip</label></br>
    <input type="text" name="cust_zip" id="cust_zip" style="width:65%" /></br>
</div>

    <input type="checkbox" name="same_box" id="same_box" >Address Same as Customer</input></br>

<label id="biz_street_label">Street</label></br>
<input type="text" name="biz_street" id="biz_street" style="width:90%" /></br>

<div id="biz_city">
     <label id="biz_city_label">City</label></br>
     <input type="text" name="biz_city_box" id="biz_city_box" style="width:100%" /></br>
</div>
<div id="biz_state">
    <label id="biz_state_label">State</label></br>
    <input type="text" name="biz_state_box" id="biz_state_box" style="width:70%" /></br>
</div>
<div id="biz_zip">
    <label id="biz_zip_label">Zip</label></br>
    <input type="text" name="biz_zip_box" id="biz_zip_box" style="width:80%" /></br>
</div>
```

Thank you very much for any help, and I apologize if I missed a topic like this in my searching.

(Also, unrelated, but why doesn't `function formReset() {
                    document.getElementById("customer").reset();
                }` work in firefox?  It only seems to work in chrome)

Comment: Try setting (a simplified version of) your code up on [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/) and posting a link here so that people can look at it (not) working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(you need to select jQuery in your JSFiddle, like http://jsfiddle.net/7HGNx/)

Your code is referring to `biz_city` but the element's id is `biz_cty_box`.

You probably don't want to attach to click, you probably want listen to the change event, as this will fire when the option is changed without the mouse. I would also check that the change has been ticking the box, not unticking the box.

```
$("#same_box").change(function (e) {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        .
        .
        .
    }
}
```

Comment: oh my god, I feel so incredibly stupid, thanks rjmunro!  a mod should delete this :X